# Primeng paginator rowsPerPageOption support for 'All'

Tags: primeng

I'm wondering if there's an equivalent solution (in primeng) to have an "All" option for rowsPerPageOptions.  Currently the only way to solve this is to add a very large number, but this isn't ideal\optimal: for instance.

```html
 <p-table #dataTable
                                 [lazy]="false"
                                 [value]="primengTableHelper.records"
                                 [paginator]="true"
                                 [rows]="rowsPerPage"
                                 [rowsPerPageOptions]="[5,10,25,50,100,100000]"
                                 [scrollable]="true"
                                 ScrollWidth="100%"
                                 [resizableColumns]="true"
                                 (onFilter)="onFilterChange()"
                                 sortMode="multiple" [multiSortMeta]="multiSortMeta">
```

I've tried adding an 'All' option, but it doesn't trigger any kind of event to be able to handle it in a custom manner (only fires events on numeric values).  Does anybody have any ideas on how I can solve this without an entirely custom solution (or the cheesy large number to catch all records).  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this config:

```
[rowsPerPageOptions]="[1,20, 50, { showAll: 'All' }]
```